# getView nullPointerException for custom List View Android

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

I have 2 custom list view which I use to display different categories. However when the second list view is created, I get this `NullPointerException` when returning from `getView`. I am unable to figure out the reason for that.

Here is the code:

**CustomListAdapter:**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context context;
    String[] stringList;
    TextView medium, small;


    public CustomListAdapter (Context con, String[] sL)
    {
        super(con, R.layout.my_list, R.id.mediumTextInList, sL); 
        context = con;

        stringList = sL;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

        View newRowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.my_list, parent,false); 


        medium = (TextView) newRowView.findViewById(R.id.mediumTextInList);
        small = (TextView) newRowView.findViewById(R.id.smallText);

        medium.setText(stringList[position]);

        return super.getView(position, newRowView, parent);
    }
```

}

**ListActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Bundle myBasket = new Bundle();

        myBasket.putString("name", categoryName);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(myFirstList.this, mySecondList.class);

        myIntent.putExtras(myBasket);
        startActivity(intent); 
 }
```

**StackTrace:**

```
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)  
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at com.umer.androiduetproject.CustomListAdapterForDeptAndSemesters.getView(CustomListAdapterForDeptAndSemesters.java:53)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1584)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
07-28 17:04:46.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
```

Regards

Comment: debug line 53 of your CustomListAdapterForDeptAndSemesters class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't supposed to call super.getView, just return newRowView.

Comment: When should we return super.getView() and when should we return just getView

Comment: if you want to inflate by yourself don't call super. especially if you want to assign values to custom leaf views

Answer (score 0):

Is there null value in `stringList`? Method `toString()` may be called in `super.getView()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    View newRowView = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

        newRowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.my_list, parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.medium = (TextView) newRowView.findViewById(R.id.mediumTextInList);
        holder.small = (TextView) newRowView.findViewById(R.id.smallText);

        newRowView .setTag(holder);
       }

     else {

          holder = (ViewHolder) newRowView .getTag();
          }

         holder.medium.setText(stringList[position]);

        return newRowView ;
    }
```